# typed async decorator in combination with asyncio.run

Tags: python, python-asyncio, typing

Have a look at the code below. I think it explains it all. Making the return value as `Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]` is the way to go I guess or should I comply with what mypy is telling me ?

```py
from typing import Awaitable, Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar
import asyncio

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")


def a_decorator(func: Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]) -> Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]:
    async def _wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        print("wrapped")
        return await func(*args, **kwargs)

    return _wrapper


@a_decorator
async def just_a_function(value1: int) -> bool:
    print(value1)
    return isinstance(value1, int)


# mypy raises an error here:
# Argument 1 to "run" has incompatible type "Awaitable[bool]"; expected "Coroutine[Any, Any, <nothing>]"  [arg-type]mypy
asyncio.run(just_a_function(10))
```

Comment: Can you try to put `functools.wraps` around the `_wrapper` function? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

Comment: @AndrejKesely that only updates the __name__ property of the wrapper function. Doesn't touch my issue.

Comment: `asyncio.run` requires specifically a `Coroutine` and not an arbitrary awaitable. While this works (because you actually return a coroutine and just annotate it broader), `asyncio.run` will not run awaitables that are not coroutines. You can confirm with `asyncio.run(asyncio.ensure_future(just_a_function(10)))` - this should raise, and return type of `asyncio.ensure_future` is awaitable (confirm by `await asyncio.ensure_future(...)` sonewhere in your current `main`).

Comment: @STerliakov Thanks. I -kind of- understand. Would it be a solution then to replace the `Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]` with `Callable[P, Coroutine[None, None R]]`. Which goes against the general advise as per example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#annotating-callable-objects

Comment: Where do you see an advice to avoid using `Coroutine` where necessary or aalways replace it with `Awaitable`? `Awaitable` has much weaker preconditions than `Coroutine`  - namely, `Awaitable` is just anything that can be `await`ed, while `Coroutine` is a complex thing (see [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/a094aa09c2aa47721664d3fdef91eda4fac24ebb/stdlib/typing.pyi#L432)). So I'd say that switching to `Coroutine` or callable protocol is a solution here.

Comment: I deduced that advise from the example as mentioned in my previous comment and from this discussion (which is not directly related, but still). https://github.com/python/typing/issues/424

But reading up on it a bit more I guess it makes sense. So thanks!